# Confirmação do action do form

Tags: jquery

Tenho esse código para excluir um registro do banco.
Como posso colocar em meu código uma confirmação jquery (sim não) de action do formlário?

```
 $('#deleteButton').on('click', function(e){
               // We don't want this to act as a link so cancel the link action
               e.preventDefault();
               doDelete();
           });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o `confirm(mensagem)` do JavaScript, que mostra uma mensagem (definida por você) para o usuário e se clicar em `Ok` ela retorna `true`, se clicar em `Cancelar` ela retorna `false`:

```
$('#deleteButton').on('click', function(e){
    // We don't want this to act as a link so cancel the link action
    e.preventDefault();

    if (confirm('Realmente deseja excluir o registro?')) {
        doDelete();
    }
});
```

O layout da janela de confirmação dessa função é o padrão do navegador, se quiser algo melhor elaborado, crie um modal customizado (bootstrap você encontra vários) por você e faça com a mesma lógica.